# Issues - Swing timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

Using swing timers for the first time, and i'm having some issues.

What am i doing wrong?

```
Random ran = new Random();
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        label.setIcon(icons[ran.nextInt(9)]);
    }
}
Timer timer = new Timer(100, ButtonListener); //Error
timer.start(); //Error
```

Comment: Yes what are you doing wrong? Did compiler complain anything? If yes what?

Comment: please 1. whats type of JComponent is label1, 2. icon1.setIcon(icons[ran.nextInt(9)]); ??? whats  whats type of JComponent is icon1, there is everything, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Make sure you've imported the right `Timer`, you don't want `java.util.Timer`, you want `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: @Holger: he's swapping the icon held by a JLabel via `setIcon(Icon icon)`. This never needs a call to `repaint()` since the JLabel automatically repaints itself whenever this occurs (please look at the source code for JLabel to see that this is so). It works similar to calling `setText(...)` on a JLabel or JTextComponent, which also don't require the programmer to explicitly call `repaint()`.

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: The first version of this question contained different code. It looked like invoking a method on `icon1`. It’s not my fault if questioners are unable to provide an SSCCE but kludging pieces of code to something containing even more errors than the one they want help for. Even his answer he gave himself still contains that error…

Comment: This is a compile time error. It seems you do not understand the difference between classes and instances. Your `ButtonListener` is a class. You can't pass that to `Timer`, you need to pass an instance. Instances are created using the `new` keyword, like this: `new Timer(100, new ButtonListener());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried a different approach which worked!

```
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        timer.start();
    }
}
Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        icon1.setIcon(icons[ran.nextInt(9)]);
    }
});
```